# Hyperbolic Square ..Call a point (x, y) in the plane . .

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Call a point $(x, y)$ in the plane hyperbolic if it lies on one of the hyperbolas $y = 1/x$ or $y = -1/x$. Find a square such that its four vertices and the midpoints of its four sides are all hyperbolic.

I trying to prove it with distance formula not with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say one of the vertices of the square is $(a,1/a)$. Then its $90^\circ$ rotations around the origin are all hyperbolic, and in particular $(-1/a,a)$, a neighbouring vertex, is also hyperbolic. Now suppose the midpoint of the two points discussed is hyperbolic and lies on $y=1/x$:
$$\frac{1/a+a}2=\frac2{a-1/a}$$
This rearranges to
$$a^2-\frac1{a^2}=4$$
$$a^4-4a^2-1=0$$
$$a^2=\frac{4+\sqrt{20}}2=2+\sqrt5$$
$$a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}$$
So for this particular value of $a$, the square formed by $(a,1/a)$ and its $90^\circ$ rotations satisfies the given conditions.

The square looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Woah I thought only in the upper two quadrants?? The square and its 4 vertices would only be in the 1/-x and 1/x ? That is where I think the authors made an error and should re word the problem for clarity . I could not see how a square could exist .

Comment: @RandinoAndantinomozartino The only problem is that the question is entirely correct. The graph of $\frac1x$ lies in two opposing quadrants, and that of $-\frac1x$ lies in the other two.

Comment: Yep I get it..and if I knew That when taking the test i would have gotten the problem , thanks for teaching me that and thanks for the visual depiction and proof . Similar triangles can be used to get the same ratio you got right ?

Comment: @RandinoAndantinomozartino Ehh, not quite. A bit of algebra _will_ be needed here.

Comment: But that's the only way you get your ratios: (1/a)+a)/2= 2/(a-(1/a)